# get text from html body

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the following html code:

```
<body class="frontend page-object" data-tealium="{"tmsData":{"ad_type":"Marktplatz","page_type":"Ad_View","vertical_id":"5","vertical":"Marktplatz","ad_title":"LEGO+Technic+8045+-+Mini-Teleskoplader+-+2+in+1","num_pictures":"4","category_level_1":"Spielen+%2F+Spielzeug","region_level_id_2":"9","category_level_3":"Lego","region_level_id_3":"117244","category_level_2":"Lego+%2F+Playmobil","region_level_id_1":"-141","price":"6","product_id":"67","category_level_max":"4","region_level_2":"Wien","region_level_3":"Wien%2C+22.+Bezirk%2C+Donaustadt","category_level_4":"Technic","seller_id":"19284847","region_level_1":"%C3%96sterreich","ad_type_id":"67","category_level_id_3":"5191","category_level_id_2":"5182","category_level_id_1":"5136","category_level_id_4":"5199","environment":"web","ad_id":"208824705","post_code":"1220","event_name":"adview","publish_date":"Sun+Jun+18+18%3A51%3A00+CEST+2017"}}" data-adid="208824705">
```

Here I try to get this category level: `"category_level_1":"Spielen+%2F+Spielzeug"` with beautifulsoup. However, I cant get it.

If I do: `CatId = soup2.select("html body.frontend.page-object")[0].get_text().strip()` I get the whole html text.

`CatId = soup2.find("html body.frontend.page-object", {category_level_1})[0].get_text().strip()` doesn't give me anything. I just need to fetch `Spielen+%2F+Spielzeug` Any idea how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The part of `data-tealium="{"tmsData" ...` in your body tag doesn't look like valid html to me, maybe fixing this will solve your issue?

Comment: Can't fix it, it is a valid html which can be found here: https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/d/lego-technic-8045-mini-teleskoplader-2-in-1-208824705/

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it with JavaScript is with:

```
const category1 = JSON.parse(document.body.getAttribute('data-tealium')).tmsData.category_level_1;

console.log(category1);
```

Make sure data-tealium is always available and JSON parseable:

```
const tealium = document.body.getAttribute('data-tealium');
const parsedData = JSON.parse(tealium);
const category1 =
  parsedData &&
  parsedData.tmsData &&
  parsedData.tmsData.category_level_1 || null;

console.log(category1);
```

Comment: Many thanks, but is there a way to get it with Python directly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much sense the results will make to you but you can see the contents of the field using Python.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/d/lego-technic-8045-mini-teleskoplader-2-in-1-208824705/').content
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> data_tealium = soup.find('body').attrs['data-tealium']
>>> info = eval(data_tealium)['tmsData']
>>> for i, item in enumerate(info):
...     '--->', i
...     item, info[item]
... 
('--->', 0)
('category_level_max', '4')
('--->', 1)
('region_level_id_1', '-141')
('--->', 2)
('ad_type', 'Marktplatz')
('--->', 3)
('seller_id', '19284847')
('--->', 4)
('product_id', '67')
('--->', 5)
('category_level_id_3', '5191')
('--->', 6)
('vertical_id', '5')
('--->', 7)
('ad_type_id', '67')
('--->', 8)
('region_level_id_3', '117244')
('--->', 9)
('category_level_4', 'Technic')
('--->', 10)
('region_level_3', 'Wien%2C+22.+Bezirk%2C+Donaustadt')
('--->', 11)
('vertical', 'Marktplatz')
('--->', 12)
('region_level_id_2', '9')
('--->', 13)
('region_level_1', '%C3%96sterreich')
('--->', 14)
('post_code', '1220')
('--->', 15)
('event_name', 'adview')
('--->', 16)
('page_type', 'Ad_View')
('--->', 17)
('category_level_1', 'Spielen+%2F+Spielzeug')
('--->', 18)
('num_pictures', '4')
('--->', 19)
('price', '6')
('--->', 20)
('category_level_3', 'Lego')
('--->', 21)
('category_level_id_2', '5182')
('--->', 22)
('ad_title', 'LEGO+Technic+8045+-+Mini-Teleskoplader+-+2+in+1')
('--->', 23)
('publish_date', 'Sun+Jun+18+18%3A51%3A00+CEST+2017')
('--->', 24)
('category_level_2', 'Lego+%2F+Playmobil')
('--->', 25)
('category_level_id_1', '5136')
('--->', 26)
('ad_id', '208824705')
('--->', 27)
('region_level_2', 'Wien')
('--->', 28)
('category_level_id_4', '5199')
('--->', 29)
('environment', 'web')
```